# Textipunt on the bottom doesn't avoid keyboard on iOS but on android does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I plan having that textinput on the bottom, and i want it to avoid the keyboard. On Android it avoids, but on iOS it doesn't, even though I'm using the `<KeyboardAvoidingView>`.

I'm placing it on the bottom with absolute position.
By the way, I'm using expo-cli

#### This is my return

```
return (

  <KeyboardAvoidingView 
    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "positionx" : false} 
    style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", bottom: 0, position: "absolute", flex: 1 }}
  >

    <SafeAreaView style={styles.commentView}>
      <TextInput
         style={styles.commentInput}
         placeholder='Comentário'
      />
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{ color: "#F5A962" }}>Publicar</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>

  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
)
```

#### This is my stylesheet

```
commentInput: {
  height: 40,
  width: "80%",
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderRadius: 5,
  borderColor: "black",
  paddingStart: 10,
  marginEnd: "3.5%",
  backgroundColor: "#eee"
},
commentView: {
  flexDirection: "row",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I misstyped "position" to "positionx", I changed it, still doesn't work

Comment: Hi there, can you include a picture so that others can see how it looks like?

Comment: Yes, you can see it [here](https://imgur.com/a/UKkeZIE)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can not solve it with the above code. You always will see the covered issue by the keyboard. it depends on the layout. If you are going to solve this problem, please feel free to create a google meeting(reactnativeseniordev@gmail.com). I will help your problem via a calling.